# Googlebot-Image incorrectly crossing domain URLs

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt, cdn

My website (`www.example.com`) has all of my images hosted via CDN under a different sub-domain (`cdn.example.com`).

We've noticed an odd behavior recently, that seems as though `Googlebot-Image/1.0` is trying to crawl valid *image* URLs from the CDN domain but prefixed with our site domain (or adding a leading slash?).

e.g. instead of requesting the image at `https://cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`, it is attempting to request `https://www.example.com/https:/cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`

This has resulted in hundreds of thousands of exceptions per week being logged on our main site, as the actual URLs are invalid.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this, other than programming the site itself to handle the malformed URLs?

Would disallowing Googlebot-Image on the `www` domain prevent it from successfully crawling the `cdn` domain?

Do I need a robots.txt file on the `cdn` domain itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to a malformed URL in your web pages.  Notice that `https://www.example.com/https:/cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg` only has one slash in `https:/cdn` instead of two.  If your page has a `<img src="https:/cdn.example.com/..."` it may be interpreted as a relative link.

The solution would be to find all image URLs in your site and make sure they are well formed with two slashes.  Alternately, you could use protocol relative linking that starts with two slashes: `<img src="//cdn.example.com/..."`.

On your web server, you could redirect URLs that contains "http:/" like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*(https?):/{1,2}(cdn\.example\.com/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1://%2 [R=301,L]
```

This will handle all the following requests having `http` or `https`, one or two slashes, and optionally a path prefix:

- `https://www.example.com/https:/cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`
- `https://www.example.com/http:/cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`
- `https://www.example.com/https://cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`
- `https://www.example.com/some-path/https:/cdn.example.com/product/12345.jpg`